# Cannot extract tags with classes specified in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first ever question. I have spent hours reading similar questions and I am sorry I still cannot figure out the problem here.

I am trying to parse a large html, the relevant part is this:

```html
<li class="offer-params__item">
    <span class="offer-params__label">Classe der ware</span>
    <div class="offer-params__value">
        <a class="offer-params__link" href="https://www.bla.com">Classe 1</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

this is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

parameters = soup.findAll("li", {"class" : "offer-params__item"}) 
print(len(parameters))

for item in parameters:
    for li in item:
        code = li.find_next('span').text.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]
    print(code)
```

Also, it prints `len(parameters)` as zero, it is not catching them. I also tried with regex without success.

Comment: Hey Sanardi, can you share the link that you are trying to scrape from?

Comment: The most likely reason is that your page is generated dynamically and you don't get the HTML tags you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<li class="offer-params__item">
    <span class="offer-params__label">Classe der ware</span>
    <div class="offer-params__value">
        <a class="offer-params__link" href="https://www.bla.com">Classe 1</a>
    </div>
</li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

parameters = soup.find_all("li", {"class" : "offer-params__item"}) 
print(len(parameters))

for li in parameters:
    for sp in i.find_all('span'):
        print(sp.text.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0])
```

you get:

```
1
Classe
```